# Cannot print the desired output

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C language. I am trying to solve a high school assignment using functions. I should write 4 functions to calculate the largest, smallest, sum and average number stored in an array of int numbers.

The problem is, i don't see the desired output. What am i doing wrong?

Here's the code

```
/**
 * Scrivere un programma che dato un insieme di numeri in ingresso (tastiera), effettua le seguenti operazioni:
 *
 * a. stampa a video la somma dei numeri inseriti
 * b. stampa a video il massimo dei numeri inseriti
 * c. stampa a video il minimo dei numeri inseriti
 * d. stampa a video la media dei numeri inseriti
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(int numbers[], int input)
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        total = total + numbers[i];
    }
    return total;
}

int smallest(int numbers[], int input)

{
    int small = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < small)
        {
            small = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return small;
}

int largest(int numbers[], int input)
{
    int large = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > large)
        {
            large = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return large;
}

float average(int numbers[], int input)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }
    float result = sum / input;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int array[100], input, number, min, max, addition;
    float avg;
    printf("How many numbers do you want to work with?: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);
        array[i] = number;
    }

    min = smallest(array, input);
    max = largest(array, input);
    addition = sum(array, input);
    avg = average(array, input);

    printf("\nsmallest number: ", min);
    printf("\nlargeest number: ", max);
    printf("\nsum of numbers: ", addition);
    printf("\naverage: ", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see my output:

[image]

any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `%d` in the format strings that will be replaced with the number. Go back and reread the section of your textbook on how to use `printf()`.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: `average()` should use the `sum()` function, instead of repeating the loop that calculates the sum.

Comment: another nit, you can start your loops in `smallest` and `largest` at `int i = 1` since you've already initialized to the first number in `numbers`.

Comment: @Barmar Would be a good idea to also point out that integer division converted to float will return a truncated amount. 4 / 3 = 1.0, not 1.33 as seems to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function's format string requires a [format specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) to go with every value you want to format into the format string.

E.g.

```
    printf("\nsmallest number: %d", min);
```

vs.

> ```
>    printf("\nsmallest number: ", min);
> ```